# Should I delete an old, unanswered question that I wouldn't ask again today?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

When I was relatively new here and just learning Python, I asked a question about initializing objects that I thought might be worth some discussion, or might not - I figured I'll ask it and see, if it gets closed, then I learned something.

Well, that question has been sitting there for a year now. I edited it a few times as I learned more about SO and what's appropriate, but other than one comment, it's gotten no action.

If this was a question that I was still interested in, I'd post a bounty - but to be honest, now that I have a little more experience, I'm not sure it was even worth asking a year ago. I wouldn't ask it today, and if I were answering, I'd say "this is largely a style decision" and flag it as too broad/opinion based.

Since it has no answers I could just delete it; I only hesitate because in all this time it was never put on hold or closed. I'm not sure that implies it's a *good* question, but if hundreds of other users have chosen *not* to flag it, maybe I should just leave it alone?

What do you think, metaheads?

The specific question is [Passing a collection argument without unpacking its contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17223607/2359271).

Comment: why not compose a good answer for those in a similar situation?

Comment: I agree that at a glance it sounds primarily opinion based, but it's otherwise a really good question; it's well-formatted, it's clear what you're asking, and it's clear that you put a lot of thought into it (rather than just mindlessly formulating the question and throwing it onto the site). I'd be happy if 10% of the "on-topic" questions had this much care.

Comment: @Plutonix If a novice programmer came to me today asking this question, I'd probably tell them they should just pick a convention, write a lot of code, and see how it turns out. That's not what I'd call a good answer in SO terms, though.

Comment: perhaps if you were to explain **why** it doesnt matter, it might make a better answer

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you have an old unanswered question that you now know the answer to, you should answer it and accept it as per the Q&A style recommendation when asking questions, and in the future it may help others who are looking for the same type of information, who may then upvote it.

The most likely outcome is that you get reputation points from helping others. And that's a win-win for everybody.

Comment: What if you don't know the answer? And it's apparent that nobody does?

Comment: Eventually, someone may see it who knows and may answer, and if the system doesn't delete it, it views it as worth keeping, so why delete it yourself? Besides, deleted questions can count against your ability to ask new questions, so... don't delete your questions.