# Is it bad practice to delete my questions I'm no longer interested in?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

A long time ago, in a job far, far away, I asked the question: [Error when connecting web parts in code-behind file (Sharepoint 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843430/error-when-connecting-web-parts-in-code-behind-file-sharepoint-2010).

I never solved the problem, the question was viewed only 379 times and the answer wasn't really applicable to my situation, and I'm no longer in a position to verify (or care about) any future answers it may receive. I accept that the question probably just wasn't very good.

Neither the question nor the answer had any up-votes or down-votes. It was, simply, a waste that I expect would *eventually* have been cleared away by the SE Roombas.

When I went to delete it however, I got a warning saying that deleting questions with answers could lead to a question ban. I've some confidence that my other contributions to the site will negate any negative impact from deleting a single question, but I was wondering if the community considered this bad form?

Comment: If the question has had hardly any feedback at all, let alone positive feedback, I would guess that we're not losing much by deleting it if it's no longer relevant. Your statement about your other contributions is spot-on though. The warning is simply there as a timely reminder.

Comment: Related: [Should I delete an old, unanswered question that I wouldn't ask again today?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256811/2359271)

Comment: Yes, it is bad (if the question has responses).

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ If it had responses that were not upvoted once in three years, it doesn't seem like a bad thing to me.

Comment: Speaking from the perspective of a reader of SO: I sometimes find questions like these which give me faith that at least I'm not the only person with this error, and I'm probably not having some bizarre issue like a file corrupted in exactly the wrong way or some such. Whether that's worth keeping it around or not, I leave to you.

Comment: @ChrisHayes [I see your point…](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: Aren't questions with more views and more +1's favored by the search? Meaning more widely useful questions are more likely to appear in results, less useful questions are less likely to appear in results? My point being, what's the harm in leaving them out there?

Comment: @bobanahalf a) I think that what the SE search prefers probably doesn't matter a great deal in terms of the views a question will get, Google will be the main driver of traffic to any question. b) there's no "harm" other than vanity for having an unanswered question be the top one on my profile, just like there's no "harm" in deleting it. it was a choice between two harmless actions. some questions can't be made more useful because they're just bad questions, or the wrong question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning about being blocked when deleting question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281464/warning-about-being-blocked-when-deleting-question)

Answer (score 59):

I could not see the question as it seems you have already deleted it. In my view, if it does not have anything embarrassing, there is no need to delete. Consider it as community property. Given that there were no activity means that you no longer are getting disturbed either. The solution provided may work for someone. Deletion would mean that you are considering QA as your personal property and removing from your shelf if not useful. In my last 1.5 years with SE, I got benefited from numerous wrong and right answers. Sometimes, just seeing a similar unanswered question since long also gives me knowledge that it is really unsolvable problem. These are the factors that determine the SE policy of banning folks who delete questions with answers.

Comment: yes, but deletion is hardly binding on SO. I expected most of the activity on meta would be from people with the ability to see deleted posts, and the actual post in question isn't central to the issue. plus, I felt deleting it before bringing the topic up would avoid a bunch of people looking at / commenting on / voting on the question/answer -- didn't want to bring it up just to have someone upvote the answer that was there, thus negating my ability to do anything about the poor question.

Comment: plus, there was a bit of the "users don't read popups until after they click ok" in there. :)

Comment: +1 For obscure topics, bad questions and wrong answers are much more helpful than no questions or answers at all.

Comment: @alx9r That sounds very relevant - but why is it more helpful?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel [Here's one good example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286784/is-it-bad-practice-to-delete-my-questions-im-no-longer-interested-in/286849?noredirect=1#comment159278_286784).  Another reason is that bad questions and wrong answers are often the intersection of "search terms that seem intuitive but are unhelpful" and "search terms that lead you to good results".  Without some content containing that intersection, you can't go from completely naive to good results predictably.

Comment: @alx9r Ok, the example makes sense.... but: The other reason is, like, **Wow!** *Most valid, and to the point, reason ever!* For real, that's about the part of search that is most hard to support by software. And the most important one in a sense: That first step, from having no clue, to knowing how to ask a bad, but correctable question. From there, you can just ask step by step until solved.

Answer (score 24):

You're talking about some loosely-related, but completely different things here. When you consider deleting a question that you've asked, you should be thinking only about the technical merits of the post:

1. Are people tripping over this in searches and likely being disappointed?
2. Could this be blocking someone from asking a much better version of essentially the same thing?
3. Was I asking the wrong question altogether?
4. Would time wasted by anyone that engaged with this question be minimal if it were deleted?

If you hit a 'yes' across the board there, then you might want to consider pruning it. Sometimes you set out to be brilliant and end up just making noise instead. This *should not happen very often*, and unless you strongly feel that the question is actively harmful in some manner, just leave it - we've got lots of space, don't worry.

Now - about question blocks. Deleted questions *are* considered when we calculate them, so deleting a question doesn't make it go away as far as how the system views the overall quality of your contributions. We don't just look at how many deleted questions you have, but also how frequently and *recently* you've deleted stuff. It's not a simple calculation that says "if more than [x] percent deleted then evil" - it's a sliding scale. To that, there's some very simple advice:

***Favor editing and improving posts over deleting them, delete only when there's no way it can be salvaged and you just don't want the embarrassment.***

Most users don't need to worry about that. What you *do* need to worry about is a moderator noticing that you're deleting quite a bit of content, and stepping in to ask you why. Remember, once you post it, it belongs to the entire community - and it's a moderator's job to protect it.

Occasionally deleting something that you feel is just not worth keeping around? That's not going to hurt you.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your response. Will try and address your points shortly. One thing I'm wondering from your post, though: Are Deleted questions treated **any differently** to other questions in regards to question blocks? So, will deleting stuff that one reasonably assumes has no impact on a question block (a zero-voted question) suddenly give it an impact, by virtue of it having been deleted?

Comment: @TZHX It depends. I can't go into it much more than to say, if you have a history of very low quality posts - it _can_ hurt you a bit more than if you didn't have such a history. However, the system is now pretty smart and can tell when someone is just getting the hang of it. ***None of this means anything to anyone that asks questions which are generally well-received.*** - it's not blocks you should worry about in that case, it's deleting content that might be useful to someone in a way you didn't consider. Just favor editing over deleting when possible, and you can't go wrong.

Comment: so 1) I doubt many people found it through search and didn't click off it for not being for them; 2) this was part of my reasoning -- no longer having any interest in potential future answers and the "answer" that was posted not actually addressing the issue, I felt it best I clear it and if any unfortunate soul finds themselves in the same situation, they can ask a better question more suited to them. 3) I think I was trying to get the system to just do something it didn't want to do, 4) no one had put any time into that question that anyone had shown in the 2/3 yrs had been of use to them

Comment: FWIW, iirc, this is the only question I've deleted on this site, had 1 other deleted that I know of by clean-up script some time ago but that was 0-score, 0-answer, 1 year old. Maybe had some zero-score dupes removed to?? Honestly, I don't think I'm any good at asking good questions (as you note, this one isn't particularly well focused), but I'm not bad enough that they attract the sort of attention that is fun. my decision to delete it was probably as much because I was sick of seeing it at the top of my profile. :)

Comment: "Favor editing and improving posts over deleting them, delete only when there's no way it can be salvaged and you just don't want the embarrassment." should be stressed. Rephrase, rework to make the question more useful.

Comment: @bobanahalf how do you improve a question based on a system that was in place at your former (not current) employers that you would have difficulty verifying if it *does* work anymore? Or for that matter, improving it with additional information about the environment and other helpful configuration bits... that you don't have access to anymore?

Comment: (fwiw - for tim and 10ks, my example of a former employer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491912/ - I don't have access to that schema or database anymore, nor the setup to try to reproduce it... and that's not a schema that I would *try* to create myself if I were given half a chance... so I can't add more details about it, I can't modify the schema to see if it works, I can't reproduce it myself now, etc... and frankly, I don't care about it. Anyone answering will be 'meh, here's an upvote' and it would likely serve someone with the same question better to ask it themselves)

Comment: @TimPost I hope you don't mind me inquiring in a comment to this older post, but I have a question directly related to your answer, and one not large enough to merit a meta question. I've occasionally suggested to new users to delete their *unanswered* questions once it was firmly established (in comments) that those are blatantly off-topic, or essentially due to a typo. Your answer makes me think that suggesting this is not the right thing to do. I was thinking along the lines of reducing noise, and that these questions get roomba'd eventually. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 12):

This ties into the stated goal of making Stack Exchange be a reference site as well as an interactive Q&A site. The fact that the original poster is no longer interested in a question doesn't necessary make it a bad question; it may yet draw good answers, or be edited into a form which does.

So I'd recommend leaving the question up and letting the community's review process decide what to do with it... unless the question is demonstrably offensive, misplaced, or otherwise shouldn't have been asked in the first place.

(I'm not sure this meta-goal is being achieved, but since it exists we should try to work with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're no longer interested in answer (which happens quite often - people transfer to other companies, use other technologies etc.) the only problem with leaving the question is, you won't be able to honestly accept the answer.

But **it's not a big deal**. In the past, there was the acceptance rate, and if it was too low, people looked down on it. It caused the 'issue' with the 'orphaned' questions, and the pressure to OP to either accept anything or delete the question. But it's one of the reasons that rate was removed!

You shouldn't be worried about you being no longer able to point out the best answer. It's what can be dealt by community (upvotes and downvotes on answers) and it's what is cool in Q&A!

Unless your question was a mistake, like trivial misspelling or the obvious misunderstanding of documentation, you should **leave it**. Because it can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is bad practice. It is also pointless, it hurts the Q&A spirit, and the deleted content is never truly deleted.

Cue here what [@user2876962](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2876962/user2876962) said above. The Question is linked to you by attribution, but it really belongs to the community now (see the terms of use of the site). This is not your personal support helpdesk, so just because it is not useful to YOU a.t.m. does not give you the right to delete it.

As of the posting of this answer, I could perfectly well fetch the question and the answer from google cache (it was the 5th entry, [here(for as long as G-cache holds it)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:7NoW3UYxP30J:stackoverflow.com/questions/11843430/error-when-connecting-web-parts-in-code-behind-file-sharepoint-2010%20)), two days AFTER deletion. Probably some other web cache will hold it indefinitely (and I saved a copy of the deleted Q&A in question on my storage drive just for the heck of it). So why delete?

Comment: To clean up things? Because it doesn't help anyone?

Comment: @Deduplicator how can you be even 66% sure that in 10 billion people there is not even one person that wouldn't be helped by the Q&A? Clean WHAT up? The site is practically infinite in size anyway, and irrelevant clutter is sifted down by the search algorithims anyway. By deleting you are denying that one guy that had the same problem (and if it happend once, can happen again) some clue to the solution.

Comment: Also, if the reader of this comment happens to be that one person, I saved a copy of the deleted Q&A in the OP of this meta, so ask me.

Comment: I'm honoured that you think my poor SharePoint question is worthy of you taking such a personal interest in its longevity. I wonder, from your point of view, if there is no valid reason to delete content, why is there a delete button? Though I think you're being slightly unfair and deliberately abrasive in suggesting I treat Stack Overflow, or any part of the network, as a personal support help desk.

Comment: I do wonder what you searched for to bring it up as the fifth result, though. Searching for the title brings it up as result #1 for me.

Comment: The content shouldn't be deleted, *if it's valuable*.  If the content isn't actually worthwhile it most certainly *should* be deleted.  SO is built on the premise of creating a repository of **quality** content.  Not a repository full of useless crap with a few gems mixed in here or there that people can't find without wading through piles of filth.

Comment: However, you are wrong about one thing. According to the terms of service (which is what I assume you mean when you say terms of use), subscriber content continues to be the property of the subscriber. It is *licensed* to the network to use if it wishes to, and of course the network may decide to display it even since it's subsequent removal by myself. I raised this question to judge community consensus, if such exists, on removing "useless" content but it seems the community is largely against it. Though the accepted answer of a similar question suggests otherwise.

Comment: Yes, it is called "the right to vanish" in Wikipedia. Follows the same principle.

Comment: @Mindwin I don't see how that's relevant. In SE you can just delete your account and become disassociated from it, if that is what you're looking to do, which isn't remotely close to what's being discussed here.

Comment: @servy in this gem to crap scale, where a question with zero votes up or down falls, in your opinion?

Comment: @Mindwin Votes are a fairly confidence indicator of quality; particularly with a score of zero typically means most people simply haven't evaluated it at all, so we don't *know* whether or not its valuable.  It could be a great question, and it could be a terrible question.