# What is the purpose of votes on the election questionnaire during the nomination period?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderator-election

In the **nomination period** of the Moderator Election there is a Q&A - Questionnaire.
[2016 Stack Overflow Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337571/2016-stack-overflow-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire)
People are **voting** on the Questionnaire.
Is there a purpose/value to these votes?

Comment: I don't like having votes enabled on those answers. Looking at previous questionnaire reveals that the most voted answers were usually elected.

Comment: Yes I can see that would happen

Comment: @MarounMaroun https://xkcd.com/552/

Comment: I believe American presidential elections are similar ;O)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Voting on Meta is different than on the main site; it may indicate **agreement/disagreement**. This is mentioned in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) for feature requests but extends to [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) as well. It is simply a way to support a candidate or his/her opinion, but does not influence the election in a direct way; votes on questionnaire answers **don't count** as election votes. Of course, high scoring posts are more visible and people might be more willing to vote for the author of that answer, but that's an *indirect* effect on the election.

A real world analogy: think of an upvote to a questionnaire answer as an 'I vote Trump' / 'I vote Clinton' car sticker.

Comment: I think it does influence the election in a direct way, somehow.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I agree

Comment: @MarounMaroun What I meant to say is that answer votes don't count as election votes. Isn't that clear?

Comment: @Glorfindel yes i'm clear on that, the election phase starts in 4 days

Comment: `think of an upvote to a questionnaire answer as an 'I vote Trump' / 'I vote Clinton' car sticker.` though I think they were more Clinton's stickers  :D