# Should we have moderation election Audits?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-election

I was just thinking: is it possible that some people would vote for random candidates (the first three candidates on the page, for example), because the reason for which they cast their vote is simply to earn a [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) badge? I believe moderation elections are important events, so we must try to stop any irresponsible behavior.

As a result, I think it's necessary to check whether users are voting carefully and seriously. Maybe we can have something like an election audit. Here is an example:

> Hey everyone! I'm vaultah, and this is my second nomination. I
>   answered your questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337730).
>
> A moderator is expected to be an unfair, irrational and narrow person,
>   incapable of handling delicate situations and taking responsibility
>   for their actions. I believe I fit this description.
>
> In case anyone's checking, I do not use available moderation tools.
>   I'm one of the least active close/delete/down/up-voters, and I never
>   use my Python duplicate hammer (among the top 100 hammer users). Of
>   the hundreds of flags I've cast over the past year, only two were
>   accepted. I hope this portrays me as someone who's well acquainted
>   with the site rules. Since I'm more inclined towards "field work",
>   i.e., reviewing posts as I discover them (often within the first
>   seconds of their existence), I will ignore the moderator flag queue if
>   elected.
>
> I neither participate in Meta (mostly silently), nor help managing the
>   Python chat room on this site and expect to collaborate with the
>   community worse as a moderator.
>
> Lastly, I have no time to moderate on neither weekdays nor weekends,
>   and would reduce the moderator coverage in Eastern Europe.

<sub>I randomly picked a candidate post, and it happened to be the post of @vaultah. Please don't take this personally. You're just lucky :)</sub>

Someone who have read this post in detail would definitely not vote for this forged candidate. However, if a user choose this candidate, he or she should receive some *severe* penalties (not able to elect or be elected as a moderator for two years, for example).

What's your opinion?

Comment: Thanks, I had a good laugh :) To make this comment constructive: I think you overestimate the usefulness of such audits. In my opinion they would only introduce even more confusion about the election process.

Comment: If people truly were voting for random candidates, or were voting for the first candidates on a randomized list, wouldn't that just even itself out? With enough votes cast, it wouldn't materially affect the outcome.

Comment: @BradLarson Yeah, randomizing candidates' order makes the Election much more fair.

Comment: *"would reduce the moderator coverage in Eastern Europe."* Sounds ominous.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are, frankly, a lot of problems with this proposal. Here are a few.

First, what would be the point of this, really? Annoying users and making them vote twice, once as an audit and once for real? This would annoy users horribly. It would certainly annoy me.

Second, how would you even know when the user was *really* voting, as opposed to try to pass the audit? What if the user votes based on the audit, thinks they've voted, and never really votes? We'd end up missing out on lots of votes, not to mention getting lots of flawed votes, where the best candidates got skipped somehow.

Third, there's nothing wrong with randomizing the candidate order, which is what we do now. In fact, with as many voters as we have, that ought to perfectly solve the problem, if it's even a real problem.

Fourth, this is not how life—or this site—works. At some point, you have no choice but to assume people are not *entirely* incompetent. Otherwise, we wouldn't have any real democratic processes anywhere in the world, much less on this site.

Fifth, everyone makes mistakes. "Fat finger" accidents happen, like [that time Tim lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught). We shouldn't penalize someone drastically for clicking the wrong button one time.

Sixth, as animuson pointed out in the comments, we absolutely shouldn't change the posts of real candidates. Users who have paid attention during the nomination and primary phases are probably not even reading the nomination posts during the election phases because they already know how they want to vote; they're just looking for names. Also, there's a real risk of reputational harm. Imagine if a potential employer sees a nomination post that says, "Hi, I'm [job applicant]. I'm lazy, irresponsible, ignorant, and unreliable." Not good.

Finally, to the extent you're trying to catch "robo-voters," that's mostly impossible. You have a sample size of only 3. It's just not comparable to robo-reviewing, where we have much larger samples and much more information about how reasonable the review was or wasn't.

Comment: Not to mention users who already know who they want to vote for before the election phase begins, and just looks for the names. I can't say I read any of the descriptions during the election phase. I already read them long ago.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, if OP means we should actually create bogus versions of real nominations, that's probably my biggest concern with the proposal. I wasn't sure if that's what OP meant.

Comment: I mean, we'd better keep an eye on potential robovoters, typically low rep users and users who participates in an election for the first time (including me), who may vote irresponsibly on purpose or due to their ignorance of how a SO moderation election works. Audits are not shown to every user, only potential robovoters mentioned above are specially "cared". Also, audits are not bogus versions of real nominations. They are completely forged, so serious voters who look for names won't vote for them. However, having read your reasonable answer, I feel using audits is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Wait a second, why users must "vote twice, once as an audit and once for real"? Their votes should be vaild if none of the audits, which are mixed with real candidates' posts, are not in their choices. Also, I'm not going to change the posts of real candidates. Audits should be handicrafted by human beings(moderators or employees). I think this is possible, because we don't need a lot of audits.

Comment: @SunQingyao I understand what you're saying. I'm saying (1) it's not necessary (see my third point above) and (2) it's not a good way to fix the problem. And how would you determine who should see the audits? You wouldn't have any relevant history to work with; you'd be assuming that users with certain characteristics are less competent than others.

Comment: @SunQingyao As for mixing them in with real candidates: what's the point? If they're included in the first 3 posts, they're incredibly obvious. If not, they do nothing to prevent people from picking the first 3 candidates on the page. And, again, the order in which the candidates are shown is random. *If* anyone is "robo-voting," they're just cancelling out the votes of other robo-voters who saw the candidates in a different order. So there's a little noise in the vote totals. That's unavoidable and *extremely* unlikely to swing an election.

Comment: Although I believe a number of users (who would presumably share some characteristics) would vote for obvious audits included in the first three posts, I agree with you in general. And I love your idea that random votes can cancel out each other.

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why this has become such a concern this year, but this is the third post I've read this election about what is essentially robo election voting. This is a non issue at this point in my opinion.

Robo reviewing is a far more critical issue to address than this (non) issue, which is why the review audits are necessary.

For each review, there are one to five people who actually review it. A bad review is 20% to 100% of the review. It is harder to find and deal with a bad review simply because not enough people see each review.

Whereas a single voter (three votes) in a moderator election is less than 0.01% of the vote tally. It would take a lot of robovoters to really influence the election. So why make voting harder or more complicated by introducing audits?